# Dubious error with a java script game

Tags: javascript

So I've been doing some practice runs on codecademy and came across a small problem. The objective is to create a rock paper scissors game in java script.

I get the following error when I try to run my code: "Oops, try again. Your code returned 'paper wins' instead of 'undefined' when the inputs are scissors and paper"

I've narrowed down the problem to the "else if" which I will highlight below:

```
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);



var compare = function(choice1,choice2)
{



    if(choice1 === choice2) 
    {
        return ("The result is a tie");
    }

     else if(choice1 === "rock") 
     {

        if(choice2 === "scissors") 
        {
         return ("rock wins");
        }
     }
```

> ```
>         ***else if (choice2 === "paper")
>         {
>             return ("paper wins");***
> ```

```
        }

    else if (choice1 === "paper") 
    {
        if (choice2 === "rock") 
        {
            return "paper wins";
        }  

    }    
             else if (choice2 === "scissors")
            {
                return "scissors wins";
            }


                else if (choice1 === "scissors")
                {
                    if (choice2 === "rock")
                    {
                        return "rock wins";
                    }
                }

                else if (choice2 === "paper")
                {
                    return "scissors wins";
                }


};

compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

So it is interesting that if I make the code that I highlighted the following:

```
***
```

> else if (choice2 === "paper")
>           {
>               if (choice1 === rock) 
>               {
>
> ```
>     return ("paper wins");
>         }
>     }
> ```

---

Then everything functions without a problem.

I was wondering why I am getting an error, if the code seems perfectly reasonable with the code that I first highlighted using only the "else if" statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` and `else if` statements are not properly nested.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);



var compare = function(choice1,choice2)
{

    if(choice1 === choice2) 
    {
        return ("The result is a tie");
    }

     else if(choice1 === "rock") 
     {

        if(choice2 === "scissors") 
        {
         return ("rock wins");
        }
        else if (choice2 === "paper")
        {
            return ("paper wins");
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") 
    {
        if (choice2 === "rock") 
        {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "scissors")
        {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors")
    {
        if (choice2 === "rock")
        {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "paper")
        {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
};

compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

Comment: That is the correct solution. Do you know why I can't  close the bracket after the first if statement? i.e: 

else if(choice1 === "rock") 
     {

        if(choice2 === "scissors") 
        {
         return ("rock wins");
        }
};

You closed it after the following else if statement:

else if(choice1 === "rock") 
     {

        if(choice2 === "scissors") 
        {
         return ("rock wins");
        }
        else if (choice2 === "paper")
        {
            return ("paper wins");
        }
    }

Comment: Because the `choice2 === "paper"` check needs to happen while the `choice 1 === "rock"` condition is known to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your logic for comparison, I guess you should also differentiate who won (i.e. Computer or User).

```
var userChoice = prompt('Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?');
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = 'rock';
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = 'paper';
} else {
  computerChoice = 'scissors';
}
console.log('Computer: ' + computerChoice);
console.log('User Choice: ' + userChoice);
var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
{
  var _result;
  if (choice1 === choice2)
  {
    _result = 'The result is a tie';
  } 
  else
  {
    if (choice1 === 'rock') {
      if (choice2 === 'scissors') {
        _result = 'rock wins';
      } else if (choice2 === 'paper') {
        _result = 'paper wins';
      }
    } else if (choice1 == 'scissors') {
      if (choice2 === 'rock') {
        _result = 'scissors wins';
      } else if (choice2 === 'paper') {
        _result = 'scissors wins';
      }
    } else if (choice1 == 'paper') {
      if (choice2 === 'rock') {
        _result = 'paper wins';
      } else if (choice2 === 'scissors') {
        _result = 'scissors wins';
      }
    }
  }
  return _result;
}
alert(compare(computerChoice, userChoice));
```

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/08kh73gy/3/) fiddle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems pretty messy to be honest.
Whenever my code gets messy I try to rethink the solution. Usually "the easiest to understand" solutions are "the best" solutions.

So, first decide upon the rules. In your case the rules are predefined.

- **rock** *beats* **scissors**
- **scissors** *beats* **paper**
- **paper** *beats* **rock**

Then, make sure the rules are followed when you're writing your code. Make sure you don't leave out any possible scenario.
Now, the first player can have 3 possible moves, which are the following:

```js
if ( choice1 === "rock" ) {

} else if ( choice1 === "paper" ) {

} else if (  choice1 === "scissors" ) {

}
```

For each of these 3 choices, the second player can have 3 possible moves as well.
For instance:

```js
if ( choice1 === "rock" ) {

     if ( choice2 === "rock" ) {
        return "it's a tie";
     } else if ( choice2 === "scissors" ) {
        return "rock beats scissors (player1 wins)"
     } else if ( choice2 === "paper" ) {
        return "paper beats rock (player2 wins)"
     }

}
...
```

Then you do the same for the other 2 cases, but make sure your code returns a result inside each of the 3 main branches. After the code makes sense to you and you test it, you can do other optimizations, like checking if the choices are equal so that you don't have to do it in every branch (the way to you did it), but remember to go for the easiest to understand solution first.

Comment: Not bad, but why don't you use "if (choice1 === choice2)" to denote a tie instead of repeating each variable over and over again.

Comment: I understood the logic and making each variable into a tie  seems redundant. The issue was "paper" wasn't getting checked with the way I had nestled it. 

as far as: "After the code makes sense to you and you test it, you can do other optimizations, like checking if the choices are equal so that you don't have to do it in every branch (the way to you did it), but remember to go for the easiest to understand solution first." 

Would be nice if you could have provided an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and the code looks quite similiar, I have tested it and works fine, it's only codeacademy's message what does not seem to work, if I'm not wrong.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

console.log("User: " + userChoice);

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
        console.log("The result is a tie!");
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {

        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }

    else if (choice1 === "paper") {

        if (choice2 === "rock") {

            return "paper wins";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "scissors wins";
        }


    }

    else if (choice1 === "scissors") {

        if (choice2 === "rock") {

            return "rock wins";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "paper wins";
        }


    }


};        

compare(userChoice, computerChoice)
```